# Issue with Firebase with next js Authentication Flow: Unverified Email Triggers "auth/email-already-in-use" Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I'm encountering a puzzling issue while implementing user registration with Firebase Authentication in my Next.js application. Specifically, when attempting to register a new user with an unverified email address, the code erroneously proceeds to the catch block and triggers an "auth/email-already-in-use" error instead of executing the intended flow to send an email verification.

Context:

I'm using Next.js for my web application development.
Firebase Authentication is integrated into my Next.js application to handle user registration.
The registration process involves creating a new user with an email and password.
Upon successful registration, an email verification should be sent to the user.
Problem:

When attempting to register a new user with an unverified email address, the code incorrectly proceeds to the catch block and triggers an "auth/email-already-in-use" error.
This behavior is unexpected because the email is not already in use; it simply requires verification.
Expected Behavior:

When registering a new user with an unverified email address, the code should send an email verification without triggering the "auth/email-already-in-use" error.
Attempts Made:

I have verified that the Firebase project settings are correctly configured to allow unverified users.
I have reviewed the Firebase Authentication documentation and ensured that the code follows best practices for handling email verification.

```
    const handleRegistration = async (registerData: FormData) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  try {
    const app = initializeApp(fireconfig);

    const auth = getAuth(app);

    if (registerData.password.length < 8) {
      setPasswordErrorMessage("Password must have at least 8 characters. ");
      return;
    }

    if (passwordErrorMessage !== "") {
      setPasswordErrorMessage("");
    }

    const userCredential: any = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      registerData.email,
      registerData.password
    );
    if (!userCredential.user.emailVerified) {
      // Send email verification
      await sendEmailVerification(userCredential.user);
      toast({
        title: "Email Verification Sent. Please verify your email.",
        status: "success",
        position: "top",
        duration: null,
        isClosable: true,
      });

      const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", userCredential.user.uid);

      // Check if the user already exists in the 'users' collection
      const userDocSnapshot = await getDoc(userDocRef);

      if (!userDocSnapshot.exists()) {
        const userData = {
          firstName: registerData.firstName,
          lastName: registerData.lastName,
          email: registerData.email,
        };

        await setDoc(userDocRef, userData);
        router.push("/login");
        return;
      }
    }
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
      setErrorMessage("That username is taken. Try another");
    }
  } finally {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the email address has already been registered with Firebase Authentication.

Calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` with an email address that has already been registered raises the `auth/email-already-in-use` error that you get. This is the intended behavior, because `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` should only be used to initially register the user. After that, you should use `signInWithEmailAndPassword` to sign them in.

Comment: when using Next.js with Firebase, I'm encountering an issue related to email verification. I want to implement a feature where if an email verification is sent to a user and for some reason they don't verify their email within a certain timeframe, then if they attempt to sign up again with the same email, instead of displaying a message saying "username already in use," it should resend the email verification.

Comment: That use-case makes sense, but your mapping to the API won't work - hence my explanation of the API: calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` with an email that was already registered leads to the error you're getting. You'll either need to call `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, or you'll need to delete the account before re-creating it.